# how to represent list in resultset

Tags: java, hashmap, resultset

I am getting the resultset value as

```
 Winter    1001    112 ,
 Summer    1001    112 ,
 Autumn    1001    110 ,
 Spring    1001    111,
 Winter    1002    112 ,
 Summer    1002    116 ,
 Autumn    1002    110 ,
 Spring    1002    115,
```

I need to present data as

```
data : [112,112,110,111][112,116,110,115]
```

The code:

```
linkedHashm = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    linkedHashm.put(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
    caltList.add("\"" + rs.getString(2) + "\"");
    dataList.add(rs.getString(3));
}
```

but as key is not unique, hashmap isnt working.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to store a list of values for each key:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
while (rs.next()) {
    multimap.put(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
}
```

Then to display it calling

```
String s = "";
for (Object v : multimap.asMap().values()) {
    s += v;        
}
```

would create the string

```
[112,112,110,111][112,116,110,115]
```